# How to convert string to json on server side?

Tags: javascript, json

I am sending a post request which has data in stringified form like this:

```
slackApi.post(
      "/send-message-to-selected",
      JSON.stringify({
        msg,          <---  In string form already
        msgLayout,
        users,
        token,
      })
    );
```

Being in string form, the data on server side gives me `msg` Object in this form:

```
'{\n' +
    '\t\t\t"type": "section",\n' +
    '\t\t\t"text": {\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t"type": "mrkdwn",\n' +
    `\t\t\t\t"text": "Hello, Assistant to the Regional Manager Dwight! *Michael Scott* wants to know where you'd like to take the Paper Company investors to dinner tonight.\\n\\n *Please select a restaurant:*"\n` +
    '\t\t\t}\n' +
    '\t\t},\n'
```

How can I convert this into JSON Object ?

Comment: `JSON.parse` it?

Comment: Convert `msg` on the client into a JSON object (`JSON.parse`) before adding it to the object you're using the `JSON.stringify` function on. Or, parse the JSON twice on the server. Also, be aware that what you're stringifying on the client is not a commonly used object because it lacks they `key: value` assignments.

Comment: @VLAZ I tried I am getting , ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 266```

Comment: @V.Sareen your JSON is invalid. Generate valid JSON and it would work. There is a `,` at the very end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you parse the JSON using `JSON.parse`, then it will turn stringified JSON into an object:

```js
JSON.parse(msg)
```

The last character is a comma and new line, so slice the string

```js
msg.slice(0, msg.length-2)
```

Comment: Yes, but 3, not just 1 ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment - 3 of what?

Comment: ",\n" are actually 3 characters, not just 1. The comma is still there when I'd do it your way.  Just tried it. EDIT: 2, not 3, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Just choose **JSON.parse()** - It should be smart enough to ignore the white space characters

EDIT: As express123 mentioned you have to remove the last 2 characters from the string:

```
msg = msg.slice(0, msg.length-2)
```

Comment: Yes, i tried it, but I am getting ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 266```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = '{\n' +
  '\t\t\t"type": "section",\n' +
  '\t\t\t"text": {\n' +
  '\t\t\t\t"type": "mrkdwn",\n' +
  `\t\t\t\t"text": "Hello, Assistant to the Regional Manager Dwight! *Michael Scott* wants to know where you'd like to take the Paper Company investors to dinner tonight.\\n\\n *Please select a restaurant:*"\n` +
  '\t\t\t}\n' +
  '\t\t},\n'

document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = input
var output = JSON.parse(input.slice(0, input.length - 2))
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = output
```

```html
<div id="input"></div>
</br>
</br>
<div id="answer"></div>
```

slice with (len - 2) removes newline char and extra comma ",/n"

Before conversion you can see the string, after conversion it shows object object.